# Right click not working wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have modded a website built by another developer that I'm attempting to do updates on. He somehow managed to disable right click on the site with or without using a plugin and I have no idea how he did it.

The website is https://meripaathshala.in

It's on WordPress using the zerif lite theme.

I'm really hoping that one of you brilliant people can help me figure out how to re-enable right clicking on the site.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The script that's disabling right-click can be found here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    document.oncontextmenu = function() {
        return false;
    };

    ...
</script>
```

Now, as to where that script is being included in the page is anyone's guess. I would start by looking in your theme's footer or functions file.

Comment: I have tried searching in theme's footer and function as well as other files which I seem must be but still not succeeded. Hope you could guess further or if I had used any plugin that I hadn't remembered.

Comment: You could try disabling all plugins and see if the issue persists. If it doesn't then it's coming from one of your plugins, if it does, then it's definitely coming from somewhere within your theme's files.